# Read complex csv consist of multiple tables in python

Tags: python, csv

I try to read .csv file in python and it comes up with following headers:

Date,Video
12.11.2020,https://link_to_video
ID,"Parent Id",Author,Date,Likes,Comment
Some data
Date,Video
12.11.2020,https://link_to_video
ID,"Parent Id",Author,Date,Likes,Comment
etc.

it has ',' delimiter, but multiple headers make my mind blow.
One idea to go through each row and if row='Date and video' skip this and next row. But it seems to be not really efficient way. Would be very appreciated for any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with REALLY not efficient code, but it worked out.
Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs
csv_reader = codecs.open( "results.csv", "r", "utf_8_sig" )
line_count = 0
video_id = []
video_links = []
rows = []
for row in csv_reader:
    if 'Date,Video' in row:
        video_id.append(line_count)
    line_count+=1
    rows.append(row)

video_len = []
for i in range(1, len(video_id)):
    video_len.append([video_id[i-1]+2, video_id[i]])


dfs = []
header = ['ID', '"Parent Id"', 'Author', 'Date', 'Likes', 'Comment']

for i in range(len(video_len)):
    video_raw_ds = []
    videolink = rows[start-1].split(',')[1][:-2]
    start = video_len[i][0]
    end = video_len[i][1]
    for j in range(start, end):
        if j == start:
            continue
        row = rows[j]
        if len(row) <= 5:
            drop_counter += 1
        else:
            row = row.split(',')
            text = ''.join(row[5:]).strip('"')
            row = row[:5]
            row.append(text)
            if len(row) <=5: video_raw_ds[-1][-1] += text
            else: video_raw_ds.append(row)
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(video_raw_ds, columns=header)
    tmp_df['videolink'] = videolink
    dfs.append(tmp_df)

dataset = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
dataset.to_csv('formatted.csv')
```